# postfix/dovecot/mysql not sending/getting emails

Tags: mysql, postfix, dovecot

I understand that I posted this before, however I left out some very important details which apparently made a lot of people less likely to answer, here's a more detailed version.

My postfix/dovecot/mysql virtual mail system is not receiving mail and is not sending it. When sent it goes to the mail queue. I'm stumped and have no idea what to provide you with, so if you ask I will put it up.

I used this guide:
https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql

My postfix main.cf:

```
 # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


 # Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
 # line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
 # is /etc/mailname.
 #myorigin = /etc/mailname
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

  # TLS parameters
  #smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
  #smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
  #smtpd_use_tls=yes
  #smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
  #smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

  #Enabling SMTP for authenticated users, and handing off authentication to Dovecot
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination # See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for # information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

  # See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
  # information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = host.example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
#mydestination = example.com, hostname.example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost
mydestination = localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

#Handing off local delivery to Dovecot's LMTP, and telling it where to store mail
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

  #Virtual domains, users, and aliases
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
```

And which file do you need for dovecot?

Error Log

```
Oct  3 20:19:36 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22289]: warning: connect #1 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:19:46 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22289]: warning: connect #2 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:19:56 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22289]: warning: connect #3 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:20:06 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22289]: warning: connect #4 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:20:16 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22289]: warning: connect #5 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:20:26 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22289]: warning: connect #6 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:20:36 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22289]: warning: connect #7 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:20:46 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22289]: warning: connect #8 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:20:56 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22289]: warning: connect #9 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:21:06 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22289]: warning: connect #10 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:21:16 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22289]: fatal: connect #11 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:21:17 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 22289 exit status 1
Oct  3 20:21:17 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Oct  3 20:22:17 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22422]: warning: connect #1 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:22:27 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22422]: warning: connect #2 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:22:32 cheese-ubuntu postfix/postqueue[22543]: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly
Oct  3 20:22:34 cheese-ubuntu postfix/postqueue[22554]: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly
Oct  3 20:22:37 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22422]: warning: connect #3 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:22:47 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22422]: warning: connect #4 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:22:57 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22422]: warning: connect #5 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:23:07 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22422]: warning: connect #6 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:23:17 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22422]: warning: connect #7 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:23:27 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22422]: warning: connect #8 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:23:37 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22422]: warning: connect #9 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:23:47 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22422]: warning: connect #10 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:23:57 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22422]: fatal: connect #11 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:23:58 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 22422 exit status 1
Oct  3 20:23:58 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Oct  3 20:24:58 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22585]: warning: connect #1 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:25:08 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22585]: warning: connect #2 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:25:18 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22585]: warning: connect #3 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:25:28 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22585]: warning: connect #4 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:25:38 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22585]: warning: connect #5 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:25:48 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22585]: warning: connect #6 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:25:58 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22585]: warning: connect #7 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:26:08 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22585]: warning: connect #8 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:26:18 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22585]: warning: connect #9 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:26:28 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22585]: warning: connect #10 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:26:38 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22585]: fatal: connect #11 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:26:39 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 22585 exit status 1
Oct  3 20:26:39 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Oct  3 20:27:39 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22610]: warning: connect #1 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:27:49 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22610]: warning: connect #2 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:27:59 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22610]: warning: connect #3 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:28:09 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22610]: warning: connect #4 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:28:19 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22610]: warning: connect #5 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:28:29 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22610]: warning: connect #6 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:28:39 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22610]: warning: connect #7 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:28:49 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22610]: warning: connect #8 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:28:59 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22610]: warning: connect #9 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:29:09 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22610]: warning: connect #10 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:29:19 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22610]: fatal: connect #11 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:29:20 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 22610 exit status 1
Oct  3 20:29:20 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Oct  3 20:30:20 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22668]: warning: connect #1 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:30:30 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22668]: warning: connect #2 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:30:40 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22668]: warning: connect #3 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:30:50 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22668]: warning: connect #4 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:31:00 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22668]: warning: connect #5 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:31:10 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22668]: warning: connect #6 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:31:20 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22668]: warning: connect #7 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:31:30 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22668]: warning: connect #8 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:31:40 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22668]: warning: connect #9 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:31:50 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22668]: warning: connect #10 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:32:00 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22668]: fatal: connect #11 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:32:01 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 22668 exit status 1
Oct  3 20:32:01 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Oct  3 20:33:01 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22670]: warning: connect #1 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:33:11 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22670]: warning: connect #2 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:33:21 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22670]: warning: connect #3 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:33:31 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22670]: warning: connect #4 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:33:41 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22670]: warning: connect #5 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:33:51 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22670]: warning: connect #6 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:34:01 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22670]: warning: connect #7 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:34:11 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22670]: warning: connect #8 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:34:21 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22670]: warning: connect #9 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:34:31 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22670]: warning: connect #10 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:34:41 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22670]: fatal: connect #11 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:34:42 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 22670 exit status 1
Oct  3 20:34:42 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Oct  3 20:35:42 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22846]: warning: connect #1 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:35:52 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22846]: warning: connect #2 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:36:02 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22846]: warning: connect #3 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:36:12 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22846]: warning: connect #4 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:36:22 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22846]: warning: connect #5 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:36:32 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22846]: warning: connect #6 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:36:42 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22846]: warning: connect #7 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:36:52 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22846]: warning: connect #8 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:36:54 cheese-ubuntu postfix/postqueue[23102]: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly
Oct  3 20:37:00 cheese-ubuntu postfix/postqueue[23114]: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly
Oct  3 20:37:02 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22846]: warning: connect #9 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:37:05 cheese-ubuntu postfix/postqueue[23243]: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly
Oct  3 20:37:12 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22846]: warning: connect #10 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:37:22 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[22846]: fatal: connect #11 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:37:23 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 22846 exit status 1
Oct  3 20:37:23 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Oct  3 20:38:23 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23263]: warning: connect #1 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:38:33 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23263]: warning: connect #2 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:38:43 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23263]: warning: connect #3 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:38:53 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23263]: warning: connect #4 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:39:03 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23263]: warning: connect #5 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:39:13 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23263]: warning: connect #6 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:39:23 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23263]: warning: connect #7 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:39:33 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23263]: warning: connect #8 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:39:43 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23263]: warning: connect #9 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:39:53 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23263]: warning: connect #10 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:40:03 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23263]: fatal: connect #11 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:40:04 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 23263 exit status 1
Oct  3 20:40:04 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Oct  3 20:41:04 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23306]: warning: connect #1 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:41:14 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23306]: warning: connect #2 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:41:24 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23306]: warning: connect #3 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:41:34 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23306]: warning: connect #4 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:41:44 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23306]: warning: connect #5 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:41:54 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23306]: warning: connect #6 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:42:04 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23306]: warning: connect #7 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:42:14 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23306]: warning: connect #8 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:42:24 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23306]: warning: connect #9 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:42:34 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23306]: warning: connect #10 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:42:44 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23306]: fatal: connect #11 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:42:45 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 23306 exit status 1
Oct  3 20:42:45 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Oct  3 20:43:45 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23326]: warning: connect #1 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:43:55 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23326]: warning: connect #2 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:44:05 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23326]: warning: connect #3 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:44:15 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23326]: warning: connect #4 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:44:25 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23326]: warning: connect #5 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:44:35 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23326]: warning: connect #6 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:44:45 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23326]: warning: connect #7 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:44:55 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23326]: warning: connect #8 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:45:05 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23326]: warning: connect #9 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:45:15 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23326]: warning: connect #10 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:45:25 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23326]: fatal: connect #11 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:45:26 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 23326 exit status 1
Oct  3 20:45:26 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Oct  3 20:46:26 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23361]: warning: connect #1 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:46:36 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23361]: warning: connect #2 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:46:46 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23361]: warning: connect #3 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:46:56 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23361]: warning: connect #4 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:47:06 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23361]: warning: connect #5 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:47:16 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23361]: warning: connect #6 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:47:26 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23361]: warning: connect #7 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:47:36 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23361]: warning: connect #8 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:47:46 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23361]: warning: connect #9 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:47:56 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23361]: warning: connect #10 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:48:06 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[23361]: fatal: connect #11 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Oct  3 20:48:07 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 23361 exit status 1
Oct  3 20:48:07 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

I'd assume that it has something to do with these lines...

```
Oct  3 20:48:07 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 23361 exit status 1
Oct  3 20:48:07 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[18492]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

Here's the output of postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = host.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination # See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for # information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Comment: 'postconf -n' will list your configuration as postfix reads your files. Would be helpful for you to post that output. Run 'postfix check' to check your directories and permissions. Have you changed the default queue directory setup? Problems there can cause those errors.

Comment: I don't believe so, but if you could direct me to where that's stored I could tell you

Comment: I added the postconf -n results to my answer

Answer (score 0):

This was due to upgrading postfix and using old config files.

Comment: What config files? What exactly was the problem?

Comment: Master.cf was the main problem, when I updated it was looking for proxymap setting that didnt exist