# What is telling me postfix with this error: warning: connect #n to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused

Tags: centos7, postfix

Can anyone tell me what's postfix telling me with this error?

```
Feb  9 13:08:59 hostname postfix/postfix-script[23077]: starting the Postfix mail system
Feb  9 13:08:59 hostname postfix/master[23079]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Feb  9 13:11:32 hostname postfix/smtpd[23180]: warning: connect #1 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Feb  9 13:11:42 hostname postfix/smtpd[23180]: warning: connect #2 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Feb  9 13:11:52 hostname postfix/smtpd[23180]: warning: connect #3 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Feb  9 13:12:02 hostname postfix/smtpd[23180]: warning: connect #4 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Feb  9 13:12:12 hostname postfix/smtpd[23180]: warning: connect #5 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Feb  9 13:12:22 hostname postfix/smtpd[23180]: warning: connect #6 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Feb  9 13:12:25 hostname clamd[1636]: SelfCheck: Database status OK.
Feb  9 13:12:32 hostname postfix/smtpd[23180]: warning: connect #7 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Feb  9 13:12:42 hostname postfix/smtpd[23180]: warning: connect #8 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Feb  9 13:12:52 hostname postfix/smtpd[23180]: warning: connect #9 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Feb  9 13:13:02 hostname postfix/smtpd[23180]: warning: connect #10 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Feb  9 13:13:12 hostname postfix/smtpd[23180]: fatal: connect #11 to subsystem private/proxymap: Connection refused
Feb  9 13:13:13 hostname postfix/master[23079]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 23180 exit status 1
Feb  9 13:13:13 hostname postfix/master[23079]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

it happens when create a new virtual user with my postfixadmin. It created ok, but postfixadmin keep loadding without answer till I cancel and then realized that the user is created.
postfix check doesn't give me any output and postconf -n :

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps
local_transport = virtual
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
relay_domains = $mydestination
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 512000000
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 5000
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

this is postconf -M

```
dovecot    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DROhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}
amavis     unix  -       -       -       -       2       smtp 
-o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200 
-o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n   -       -       -       -       smtpd 
-o content_filter= -o local_recipient_maps= 
-o relay_recipient_maps= 
-o smtpd_restriction_classes= -o smtpd_client_restrictions= 
-o smtpd_helo_restrictions= 
-o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject 
-o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8 -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes 
-o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd 
-o syslog_name=postfix/submission 
-o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt 
-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes 
-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
flush      unix  -       -       n       1000?   0       flush
trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
```

Should I assume it's the same problem as here? 
[postfix/dovecot/mysql not sending/getting emails](https://serverfault.com/questions/633471/postfix-dovecot-mysql-not-sending-getting-emails)

I'm also receiving this dovecot error: auth-worker(1560): Error: mysql(localhost): Connect failed to database (postfix_db): Access denied for user 'postfix'@'localhost' (using password: YES) which i realized just now at the time testing imap with telnet and try to log with a already created user with and without domain, could be this related?

Comment: So, did the answer from [postfix/dovecot/mysql not sending/getting emails](http://serverfault.com/questions/633471/postfix-dovecot-mysql-not-sending-getting-emails) solve your problem?

Comment: @masegaloeh I hadn't done an upgrade, I don't know if i should and if would be useful to do that. I have postfix 2.10.1

Comment: Are you missing whitespaces before all the options with `-o` in the `master.cf`? Usually there has be at least one.

Comment: I'm not missing whitespaces in -o options @sebix , just here . I strongly believe that is a permissions issue , I will answer as soon as I know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a strange reason @masegaloeh 's answer doesn`t work with me instead when I use this, trying to solve another error, it fixed. So ain't going to say this is the right answer but I leave it anyway in case help anyone to solve similar problems.

I Just add this line in my /etc/postfix/master.cf file because I have an smtpd error like this: "subsystem public/cleanup: Connection refused"  and voilá , both errors gone.

```
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
```

Comment: Well,  you don't report to us that you also have another error `subsystem public/cleanup: Connection refused`, you only post the proxymap error log.  Anyway, congratulations for solving the problem :)

Comment: well, you know the rules @masegaloeh first I look for myself and then if I'm not able to solve it , I do ask. This error was for a long time, and the other was new. Thank for everything

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

The output of `postconf -M` will tell you the valid entry of `master.cf`.  Based of that, looks like you have missing proxymap entry. Put this line on `master.cf`

```
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
```

[Proxymap service](http://www.postfix.org/proxymap.8.html) was needed by postfix because you have set enable proxy option in main.cf. Those configurations were `virtual_alias_maps`, `virtual_mailbox_domains` and `virtual_mailbox_maps`.

Comment: The errors doesn't seem to be related to this, still having the same log messages.

Comment: DId you restart postfix? Please post the updated output of  `postconf -n` and `postconf -M`.

Comment: done (updated), by the time I test to create a new virtual mailbox I restarted dovecot, postfix and apache. Please read the updated part at the end.

Comment: Weird. 1)  can you post the output of `sudo netstat -an | grep proxymap` to verifying? 2) can you connect to mysql with the credential in maps?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same "`subsystem public/cleanup: Connection refused`" problem but when I looked at the `/etc/postfix/master.cf` file, the mentioned line was already there.
So in my case the solution was to simply restart postfix:

```
service postfix restart
```

After that, I received all the emails that weren't sent before...and that was a lot.